# GPU computing on Mac OSX Marvericks with Intel Iris Pro 1024 MB

Tags: macos, opencl, gpgpu, intel, jocl

I have a Mac OS X Marvericks with Intel Iris Pro 1024 MB and have been doing some graphics/simulation work in Processing. I have ran into performance issues with the built in perlin noise function of processing.

I plan to use GPU for computing the perlin noise (or some other value based noise) Now I have a little familiarity with Nvidia's CUDA but have no idea about Intel based chips. **I am not even sure if I can do the same here.**

As of now I went ahead and tried JOCL 0.1.9 samples and they seem to work fine. From this link: http://www.jocl.org/samples/samples.html

However I tried running the cloth simulation demo from http://www.jocl.org/cloth/cloth.html but at command line it shows the following logs:

```
    ➜  JOCLClothDemo-0.0.4a  java -cp ".:javagl-simplemesh-0.0.0.jar:javagl-simplerenderer-0.0.5.jar:javagl-utils-obj-0.1.3.jar:jocl-cloth-0.0.4a.jar:JOCL-Utils-0.0.0.jar:lwjgl.jar:lwjgl_util.jar;jocl-0.1.9.jar" org.jocl.cloth.ClothApplication
INFO   : ClothApplication: Creating renderer
CONFIG : SimpleRenderers: Found factory SimpleRendererFactoryLWJGL
CONFIG : SimpleRenderers: Found factory SimpleRendererFactoryJOGL
CONFIG : SimpleRenderers: Created de.javagl.simplerenderer.lwjgl.SimpleRendererLWJGL@69684b79
INFO   : ClothApplication: Creating renderer DONE
INFO   : ClothApplication: Creating simulator
INFO   : ClothApplication: Creating simulator DONE
WARNING: ClothApplicationGUI: No OpenCL implementation available!
WARNING: ClothApplicationGUI: No OpenCL implementation available!
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
```

Clicking on INIT on the GUI adds the following to the logs:

```
INFO   : ClothApplicationSetup: Loaded DefaultMeshPrimitives[V:26248,E:78226,F:51979]
INFO   : ClothOptimizer: Optimizing cloth data
INFO   : ClothOptimizer: Optimizing cloth data DONE - took 440.677 ms
INFO   : ClothApplicationSetup: Found simulation file for input: ./data/square_V26248_E78226_F51979.sim
INFO   : ClothApplication: Initializing simulation
INFO   : ClothApplication: Initializing simulation DONE
_NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. Exit
```

So I just need someone to point me in the right direction and let me know if its possible to write GPU code on my machine and if so it would be great if I can get a few pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a Sony VAIO with Intel GMA 5000 (Iris is GMA 5200) and am able to run C++ OpenCL code on my video card.  I can also use JavaCL to query the card.  This is all on Windows 8 though.

Comment: According to [http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5942](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5942) OS X Mavericks does support OpenCL 1.2 on your GPU, so the samples should work.  Please run JOCLDeviceQuery from the samples you linked to and post the output here.  If that demo detects a device then the problem may be with the specific demo rather than your machine.

Comment: For the same configurations, Mac OSX Mavericks with Intel Iris Pro 1024, I could get the OpeCLOfflineCompilation to run properly.